# When does HttpUrlConnection.usingProxy() return true?

Tags: java, networking

In a test, I do:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "1080");
```

and then open a connection:

```
 connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
 if (connection.usingProxy()) {
    throw new Nope();
 }
```

The proxy is being used, otherwise the connection would fail. But `usingProxy()` is returning false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a fair amount of details in [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html) that discuss the different ways proxies can be set in an application, and how the connection uses the proxies.

You can also gain a significant understanding from debugging the code itself which leads to conclusions that align with the description in the page.

Basically, `usingProxy()` returns true when the following conditions are met:

1. The connection is actually created. In your code, the `url.openConnection()` does not physically establish the connection to the URL. You need to invoke `connection.connect()` (or an action that implicitly does the connection). This is mentioned in the Javadocs of [`openConnection()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openConnection()):

   > It should be noted that a URLConnection instance does not establish the actual network connection on creation. This will happen only when calling URLConnection.connect().
2. The proxy set (either using the system properties or via the `java.net.Proxy` class) points to an accessible address. So make sure that the proxy `localhost:1080` is a valid proxy.

More details about the second point. The `HttpUrlConnection` relies on a `ProxySelector` class (mentioned in the page above), which looks up registered proxy addresses. The default `ProxySelector` will faithfully get the proxy you set in the system properties, and the `HttpUrlConnection` will try to access the proxy. If it's not available it will ask the `ProxySelector` for another proxy (if another exists).

I found the dialog that is included in the documentation to be a good explanation (the part in italic highlights the attempt to connect to the proxy):

> **Handler**: Hey dude, I'm trying to reach java.example.org, should I use a proxy?
>
> **ProxySelector**: Which protocol do you intend to use?
>
> **Handler**: http, of course!
>
> **ProxySelector**: On the default port?
>
> **Handler**: Let me check.... Yes, default port.
>
> **ProxySelector**: I see. Then you shall use webcache.example.com on port 8080 as a proxy.
>
> **Handler**: Thanks. <pause> Dude, ***webcache.example.com:8080 doesn't seem to be responding!*** Any other option?
>
> **ProxySelector**: Dang! OK, try webcache2.example.com, on port 8080 as well.
>
> **Handler**: Sure. Seems to be working. Thanks.
>
> **ProxySelector**: No sweat. Bye.

(A note that the author does mention that it is an embellished dialog.)

Comment: The dialogue is a jokey disaster, and it isn't even accurate. The selector doesn't ask any questions. It is provided with parameters.

Comment: @EJP Indeed the author mentions he or she is "embellishing a bit". I wanted to highlight the part that says the proxy is accessed before the next proxy is selected.