# Why is the JVM parameter http.proxyHost not used by tomcat servlets?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, proxy

I have a black box servlet which sends message to other server via `ebMS` (smtp / pop?). I have put the servlet in Tomcat 8.0.30 on a Linux(centOS) server and it is tested messages can be sent to other hosts through the internet. I would now like to set up proxy for the servlet via Tomcat JVM parameters as following:

```
#tomcat/bin/catalina.sh
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=abc.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888 -DproxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=def.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888"
```

I decided to test it with fake proxyHost first and if the message failed to send, it would prove that the servlet is indeed using the specified proxy setting.

The parameters are passed to tomcat after restarting service as shown in `tomcat/log/catalina.2016-01-08.log`:

```
08-Jan-2016 11:39:53.725 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttps.proxyHost=abc.com
08-Jan-2016 11:39:53.725 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttps.proxyPort=8888
08-Jan-2016 11:39:53.725 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -DproxySet=true
08-Jan-2016 11:39:53.725 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyHost=def.com
08-Jan-2016 11:39:53.725 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
...
08-Jan-2016 11:39:59.195 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 5297 ms
```

However when I test the servlet (call a java class via .sh) the message is delivered successfully and can be received at the receiver through the Internet. The proxyHost parameter is not applied.

What am I missing here? Is it possible for a servlet to override proxy settings? Or will tomcat disable the proxy setting after the given proxy cannot be resolved / timeout?

Would appreciate any insight. Thanks.

Comment: Neither SMTP nor POP3 uses HTTP proxying. Your question doesn't really make sense. If you're asking why the *client* didn't use the proxy, the answer is that `https.proxyHost` needs to be set *at the client.* Setting it at the server doesn't make sense. And if that's your question, the relevance of mentioning SMTP and POP escapes me.

Comment: @EJP There's no client in this case, I'm calling the service's class at the linux server and it would fail to run if tomcat is not online(so it's not running another client class apart from Tomcat). Is there other proxy settings for SMTP / POP3 if HTTP proxying is not applying?

Comment: Why? Has somebody closed the ports? If so, why? You should allow your Tomcat instance(s) to access the port(s) required directly.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It turns out the servlet will use http / SMTP depending on the given endpoint to be start with `http://...` / `mailto`. And the reason httpProxy not applying is also found; I will post an answer and close the question. thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will mark here the answer to the mentioned questions in case someone may find useful.

> Is it possible for a servlet to override proxy settings?

Yes it is. I've written a test page to print out `System.getProperty("http.proxyHost")` and it was not `abc.com` as I passed to the JVM. There was a `<servlet-name>.properties.xml` under the directory   `/opt/tomcat/webapps/<servlet-name>/WEB-INF/classes/...` which contains some JVM parameters, including `http.proxyHost` in xml format. It is possible that the servlet calls System.setProperty on those parameters on startup and therefore have overwritten the passed values.

> Will tomcat disable the proxy setting after the given proxy cannot be resolved / timeout?

Yes it will. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34048170/when-does-httpurlconnection-usingproxy-return-true), the proxy set has to "points to an accessible address" or otherwise it will not be returned by the `ProxySelector`.

When the proxyHost is set to point to a working proxy server in the mentioned `.properties.xml`, `System.getProperty("http.proxyHost")` prints the correct host and the message can be delivered. When I points it to an alive but not forwarding server, `System.getProperty("http.proxyHost")` prints the correct host and the message is **blocked** successfully as expected.